# how to create a option menu when user long press on list item in phonegap?

Tags: android, cordova, contextmenu

I my app I have created and list view which retrieves data from database know what  i want is when user select a list item with long press will give an option like edit,delete & cancel here is the code i had returned for list.

```
function getdata(){
 db.transaction(function(tx)
         {
            tx.executeSql(selectdata,[],function(tx,results){
                $('#name').empty();
                var neerav="dsad";
                    for(var i=0;i<results.rows.length;i++){
                    $('#name').append('<li id="s'+i+'" onclick="selectname('+i+')">'+results.rows.item(i).nameR+'</li>');
                    dataobj[i]=results.rows.item(i).nameR;
                    }                           
            });  });}

function selectname(ps){
var name=dataobj[ps];
db.transaction(function(tx){
    tx.executeSql(insrtdt,[ps,name]);
    selectdta();
});}

function selectdta(){
db.transaction(function(tx){
    tx.executeSql(slctdata,[],function(tx,results){
        var lngth=results.rows;
        var time='';
        if(lngth.length>0){
            $("#s"+ps).on("touchstart",function(){
                var d=new Date();
                time=d.getTime();
            });
            $("#s"+ps).on("touchend",function(){
                var D=new Date();
                time1=D.getTime()-time;
                if(time1>100){
                    alert("Long pressed");
                }else{
                    window.location='file:///android_asset/www/editpage.html';      
                }
            });

        }   
    });
});}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get that info easly by just looking at documentation...

If your using jQuery-mobile, just use `taphold` event: [Link](http://api.jquerymobile.com/taphold/)

Else, if you're looking for android native event: [Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html)

Comment: hey  i tried but didn't found helpful actually I'm not getting how to use it exactly